# Apache+Tomcat+jk: serving static resources in a Java EE web app

Tags: apache, tomcat7, mod-jk

I recently installed Apache w/s + Tomcat and using jk was able to route requests from apache to t/c. The examples on the net are usually of the form:

```
JkMount /*.jsp myTC
```

We have several Java EE applications running on a single instance of tomcat (then why use apache? believe me i have reasons). I figured we could change the context for each of those applications to something like:

```
/servlet/application1/
/servlet/application2/
/servlet/application3/
```

and then have something like:

```
JkMount /servlet/* myTC
```

This would route the requests to tomcat correctly, however, the question remains how to serve static resources for a standard Java EE application:

```
/webapp-root
    resources/
       css/
       js/
       images/
    WEB-INF/
       /usual-folder-structure
```

The questions are:

1. How to serve resources/ folder from apache? all the applications have their own resources/ folder. I figure resources/ will have to reside 'out' of the war and on apache's doc-root somewhere, but can't figure out the JkMount string.
2. Is the /servlet/ scheme the 'correct' way to do it? are there patterns I should follow?

I'll appreciate any help, any pointers to resources on the net would be great as I need to read a lot more about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The following should be enough:

```
JkMount /* myTC
JkUnMount /resources/* myTC
```

(2) It's OK. There are many correct solutions. I personally don't like /servlet/ in the URL. It's garbage, especially in this age where URLs are an asset of a website/webapp. I use this scheme:

```
JkMount /* myTC
JkUnMount /*.css myTC
JkUnMount /*.ico myTC
JkUnMount /*.jpg myTC
JkUnMount /*.js myTC
JkUnMount /*.png myTC
JkUnMount /*.xml myTC
JkUnMount /*.zip myTC
```

Comment: so if all three applications have their respective static resources in a folder named resources/,  apache should have docroot/application1/resouces/, docroot/application2/resources/ & docroot/application3/resources/ ?

Comment: Yes. Each application should exist in its own DocumentRoot. Unless it's some kind of setup where 3 different applications share the same static resources (highly unlikelly).

Comment: is it possible for you to point me to web based resources i could read more this. Thank you.